# Linux shell command to append a line of text to all text files (application logs actually)

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to append a line of text all text files (*.log) in a directory, reason being, i would like to insert a "marker" text in application logs to insert breakpoints.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using a 'for' loop:

```
for i in *.log; do echo "MARKER" >> "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -lne 'if(eof){print $_."\MARK"}else{print}' *.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -i '$a MARKER' *.log
```